# Using q promises with map to get file contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm trying to use the `q` promise library to get the names of `.json` files in a directory and return the contents of those files. I'm able to get the filenames, but I'm having trouble using `arr.map` in conjunction with promises in order to read the *contents* of the file. I'd like `getContents()` to return a mapped array with the contents of the specified filenames.

```
function readDir() {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    fs.readdir('users', function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getContents(filenames) {
    return filenames.map(function(filename) {
        fs.readFile('users/' + filename, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
            return result;
        });
    });
}

readDir()
    .then(getContents)
    .then(function(fileContents) {
        // currently returns undefined
        console.log(fileContents);
    });
```

How can I properly wrap `getConents()` in a promise so that the contents of my array are not equal to undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get an array of promises - that `return result` is useless in the asynchronous callback. Make a promise for every single `readFile` call:

```
filenames.map(function(filename) {
    return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'users/' + filename, 'utf8');
//  ^^^^^^ here's where the return is needed
})
```

The [`Q.nfcall` function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfcallfunc-args) basically does the same stuff that you've written out in your `readDir` function.

Now that you've got an array of promises, you can easily turn that into a promise for an array (that awaits all of them) using [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall):

```
function getContents(filenames) {
    return Q.all(filenames.map(function(filename) {
        return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, 'users/' + filename, 'utf8');
    }));
}
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to use `JSON.parse()` on the result while still using `Q.nfcall()`?

Comment: Just do `Q.nfcall(…).then(JSON.parse)` (as like for every other promise-for-JSON-text)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can define the proper async version of `fs.readFile` using promises:

```
function readFileAsync(/* ...args */) {
    return Q.nfapply(fs.readFile, arguments);
}
```

After that, you have two options. This will read the files in parallel:

```
function getContents(filenames) {
    return Q.all(
        filenames.map(function(filename) {
            return readFileAsync('users/' + filename, 'utf8');
        })
    );
}
```

And this will read them one by one:

```
function qMap(array, selector) {
    var i = 0;
    var result = [];


    function store(x) {
        result.push(x);
        return next();
    }

    function next() {
        if (i < array.length) {
            var index = i++;
            var item = array[index];
            return Q.fcall(selector, item, index).then(store);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return Q.fcall(next);
}

function getContents(filenames) {
    return qMap(filenames, function(filename) {
        return readFileAsync('users/' + filename, 'utf-8');
    });
}
```